# HttpWebResponse throws time out exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, forms-authentication

I am trying to authenticate a `HttpWebRequest`. My code is like this

```
 string url = "http://mydomain.com";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = string.Format("{0}={1}", cookie.Name, cookie.Value);
    WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
```

Everything goes fine till last line executes(*WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();*).When last line executes code execution goes back to first line(*string url = "string url = "http://mydomain.com";";*) and start again,this happens so many times that a time out exception happens.

Comment: "HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri" doesn't really look like an url :)

Comment: @VladL:it was a mistake when i pasted it.Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: can you give us proper domain so we can test it? or maybe there is another public domain there you can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - not clear why url is defined like this:

```
string url = "HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri";
```

This is not a valid URL. But if you have

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

Than you are producing a request to that same page you are in. So basically, you simply produce a loop. You call your page from a browser, it calls itself using webrequest, and it calls itself again. So in VS debugger will show you like it goes back to the first line.
Try simply change url definition like below:

```
string url = "http://wwww.google.com";
```

If you will do that,it should work fine. Basically, as I understand, you are simply using wrong URL which creates something like a loop (or even better to say: long chain of calls)

Comment: Thanks for your response.I have changed the url as you said but still it throws an error(System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse())

Comment: What url  have you used? if google - their server may be configured like that - throw out non-browser requests.

Comment: ah.nop i used my own domain.

Comment: and in VS I am gettin "Too many automatic redirections were attempted." in my try catch

Comment: Try google instead of your own domain. Just to check that it works. About redirection - that is a question to an url which you are trying to load. Redirection number is set to 50 by default, as far as I can see, so there should be some condition which force endless redirects to your request. Besides, why do you need to call your own application in that way?

Comment: I think you are correct about Redirection.Is there any way that i can overwrite the current condition like forcing to stop redirecting after first request(I know with out detecting correct problem this is wrong methode).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.maximumautomaticredirections.aspx Also, you can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx to prevent it from redirection at all

Answer (score 0):

Try to take the quotes off the `HttpContext` line:

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

You are asking for the literal URI address "HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri" instead of the actual absolute URI "http://domain.com/" that is contained in the variable `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`.

Comment: I have tried changing the URL but of no use still get "Too many automatic redirections were attempted." this error in my try catch